# Help Me Solve This Riddle

Tags: riddle

The word I'm looking for has 4 letters.

Riddle me this:

> The closer you get to it,
>
> the further away it is.
>
> What is it?

This has been bugging me all day! 
Please help me answer it.

Comment: If it's not your riddle, you should cite the source.

Comment: there wasn't a source someone just told it to me, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Noon

Because

> the closer you get to noon today, the further away noon yesterday gets.